# On click event with radio button

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, radio-button

```js
var card = document.getElementsByName("payment");

card[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
document.getElementById("something").innerHTML += "added content"})
```

```html
<div id="something">
<input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="payment" id="creditCard"value="creditCard">
</div>
```

I've added an event that adds more content to the form after an user clicks on radio button, but that radio button doesn't change color on the first click, it does add content and after the second click on that button the color changes to selected. I want it to change the color on the first click, not the second

Comment: Please add your code to the question

Comment: @HarshanaSerasinghe I've added a snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can set the radio button to the `checked` state by adding the `.checked` attribute.

```js
var card = document.getElementsByName("payment");

card[0].addEventListener("change", function() {
  document.getElementById("something").innerHTML += "added content"
  card[0].checked = true
})
```

```html
<div id="something">
  <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" name="payment" id="creditCard" value="creditCard">
</div>
```